# SQL UNION to SORT by two different ORDER BY clauses and remove duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by, union, union-all

I've researched this for the past two days on stackoverflow and the web and still not getting my desired result. Im using ORACLE 11G. I have two SQL queries with two different ORDER BY clauses. Both must retain the correct sort order. I just want to combine the two and remove duplicates as well. I have tried UNION to remove duplicates from my query and it works but does not retain my sort order for both my combined queries. How do I remove duplicates and keep both correct sort orders for each SQL query? 
Here is my query below that sorts correctly but does remove duplicates. What do I need to do? All the 2018 dates repeat once throughout the query result set. I do not want duplicates. Thanks for the help.

Here are the two queries I combined below (This is the top query):

```
SELECT FLIGHT_NMBR, SCHEDULED_LAUNCH_DATE
FROM FLIGHTS
WHERE to_date(scheduled_launch_date, 'DD-MON-YY')
BETWEEN add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'),0) 
AND add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'),6) 
AND DATA_VERSION_NAME = 'WORKING' 
AND sequence_nmbr >= 0
ORDER BY SCHEDULED_LAUNCH_DATE ASC;
```

This is the bottom part of the query:

```
SELECT FLIGHT_NMBR, SCHEDULED_LAUNCH_DATE
FROM FLIGHTS
WHERE DATA_VERSION_NAME = 'WORKING'
AND SEQUENCE_NMBR >= 0
ORDER BY sequence_nmbr asc;
```

Then here is the combined query I came up with that does not quite work like I want it to. I just wish to remove duplicates from the query below. How can I do this?

```
WITH CTE_Sets AS (
SELECT 1 AS set_order, FLIGHT_NMBR, SCHEDULED_LAUNCH_DATE
FROM flights
WHERE to_date(scheduled_launch_date, 'DD-MON-YY')
BETWEEN add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'),0) 
AND add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'),6) 
AND DATA_VERSION_NAME = 'WORKING' 
AND sequence_nmbr >= 0
UNION
SELECT 2 AS set_order, FLIGHT_NMBR, SCHEDULED_LAUNCH_DATE
FROM flights
WHERE DATA_VERSION_NAME = 'WORKING'
AND SEQUENCE_NMBR >= 0
)
SELECT FLIGHT_NMBR, SCHEDULED_LAUNCH_DATE
FROM CTE_Sets
ORDER BY
set_order,
CASE set_order
    WHEN 1 THEN SCHEDULED_LAUNCH_DATE END ASC,
case set_order
WHEN 2 THEN SCHEDULED_LAUNCH_DATE END ASC;
```

Result for my UNION query above:

```
FLIGHT_NMBR  SCHEDULED
------------ ---------
SpX-14       26-JAN-18
69P          09-FEB-18
SpX-DM1      09-MAR-18
54S          13-MAR-18
OA-9         14-MAR-18
55S          29-APR-18
SpX-15       06-JUN-18
SpX-DM2      22-JUN-18
70P          27-JUN-18
1A/R         20-NOV-98
2A           04-DEC-98
```

Comment: If that’s the exact query, note that you’re doing both sorts based on scheduled launch date, not one with that and other with sequence number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the work in the `order by` clause:

```
SELECT FLIGHT_NMBR, SCHEDULED_LAUNCH_DATE
FROM FLIGHTS
WHERE DATA_VERSION_NAME = 'WORKING' AND
      sequence_nmbr >= 0
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN to_date(scheduled_launch_date, 'DD-MON-YY') BETWEEN add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'), 0) AND add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'), 6) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END),
         (CASE WHEN to_date(scheduled_launch_date, 'DD-MON-YY') BETWEEN add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'), 0) AND add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'MON'), 6) THEN SCHEDULED_LAUNCH_DATE END),
         sequence_nmbr;
```

Note:  You should be storing `scheduled_launch_date` as a *date* column not a *character* column.

Comment: Wow this worked perfectly and did exactly what I needed it to do. Thank you. Two days of frustration gone.